# External process never Ends on while searching for all services

Tags: java, windows, cmd, windows-services, java-8

I've the following code to determinate all windows services:

```
  String QUERY = SC QUERY type= service state= all | FIND \"SERVICE_NAME\";

  ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", QUERY);
  Process p = builder.start();
  p.waitFor();

  try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(p.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1")) {

     while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        items.add(new Service(scanner.nextLine().replace("SERVICE_NAME: ", "").trim()));
     }
  }
```

Now i've the problem, that the process hangs on the method waitFor()
When I remove the argument ***state= all*** then the execution works.

Has someone a solution for that problem?

Comment: You have to read the pipe *while the process is running*. Don’t call `waitFor` without reading the pipe. It will deadlock as soon as the pipe’s buffer is full. And the buffer might be very short…

Comment: Thanks for the response. it works now after i deleted the waitFor() method